# debug native code and net code

Tags: debugging, debuggers, .net

I have a .net dll with a lot of calculations and formulas.
From this dll, I want to set breakpoints to see the calculated results for a specific field.

The main program is written in native code. So, I cannot use dnspy for debugging.

I was trying to use visual studio for my class library and set the exe file to debugger external source.

This shows me a “debugger was found” error

Can anyone help me how is the best way for my request?